# Firefox not opening window in service worker for Push message

Tags: javascript, firebase, firefox, web-push

Firebase Cloud Messaging

I have everything setup, the Push messages are received fine and when I click on it, it opens new window... but only in Chrome, in Firefox it is not opened.

I have specifically allowed popups, but didn't make any difference.

I was just debugging for 1 hour

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(e) {
    console.log("This is printed to console fine");
    clients.openWindow('https://example.com'); // this makes no error, nothing
});
```

Any ideas?

Works in Firefox 47.0

Doesn't work in Firefox Quantum 60

Subscribed a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed from the service worker:

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

And it is now working.

This is just nuts.

Comment: you save my day!
did you find some workaround to use firebase.messaging inside service worker?

Comment: @hacker13ua The issue is that you can open the window only during onnotificationclick or close, but it seems like firebase.messaging takes these events and when our handler onnotificationclick is called it is too late! If you use "event.waitUntil( clients.openWindow(your_url_address) );" it will show an error that event is not available. But if you remove firebase.messaging it works fine.

Comment: @Aurélien Warnon had a better workaround. still nuts

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled with this for a while...

To anyone else having the problem, I wanted to add something:

You can still use firebase.messaging() but you have to make sure you put it AFTER the event listener.

To make this clear:

This does NOT work (clients.openWindow does nothing):

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

// Add an event listener to handle notification clicks
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    if (event.action === 'close') {
        event.notification.close();
    } else if (event.notification.data.target_url && '' !== event.notification.data.target_url.trim()) {
        clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.target_url);
    }
});

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    // ... add custom notification handling ...
});
```

This does work (clients.openWindow opens link as expected):

```
// Add an event listener to handle notification clicks
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    if (event.action === 'close') {
        event.notification.close();
    } else if (event.notification.data.target_url && '' !== event.notification.data.target_url.trim()) {
        clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.target_url);
    }
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    // ... add custom notification handling ...
});
```

Still not sure of the underlying reason. I also suspect that the messaging() messes up the click event and makes Firefox refuse to open a window because it considers that the user took no direct action at the notification.

But at least I have a workaround and can keep going.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This fix worked for me after struggling for some time. I don't know how it is internally architected but seeing this line 173 in firebase-js-sdk/sw-controller.ts : `// Prevent other listeners from receiving the event` i think it prevents my listener from receiving the event

Answer (score 1):

Found out the reason of this.

The `Firebase.messaging` was the culprit ONLY if you send the messaging payload (from server) as such:

```
{
  "notification": {
  //...
  }
}
```

The existence of `notification` property will prevent the `notificationclick` from propagating due to some reason in the firebase sdk.

You can send the following instead

```
{
  "data": {
      //...
  }
}
```

Comment: It works differently in these 3 scenarios: browser closed / unfocused / focused. If you put the "data" key it will skip the default function that deals with the notification message and doing so will solve other issues. But it doesn't solve the issue with the window, because the onclick event is taken.